# VB 2010 array/write array to file

Tags: vb.net, arrays

*I'm close to getting this to work, but currently can't get any output to display in the listbox. I had it working, but needed to move some things around to get the join function to work.*

In my program, a user enters input into a textbox and an array is displayed in a listbox based on what they type in. For example, if they type in "a", all foods (in the textfile that is connected to the program) that start with "a" will be displayed.

When there is output, I need to find a way to name this array (which is created based on what the user inputs) and join all of the items in the listbox (example: foods stacked on top of each other in the listbox will be shown at the bottom as a string).

I am posting the code that I have thus far; all of the errors that I'm getting (and potentially my logic errors) are just in the first public class until the end of the first if-next statement:

```
Public Class frmFoods
Dim foods() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("foods.txt")


Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

    Dim Letter As String = txtLetter.Text.ToUpper
    Dim smallerarray() As Array
    Dim userarray As String
    lstOutput.Items.Clear()
    If IsNumeric(txtLetter.Text) = False Then
        For Each food As String In foods
            smallerarray = listfoods(Letter)
            lstOutput.Items.Add(Letter)
            userarray = Join(smallerarray, ", ")
            lstOutput.Items.Add(userarray)
        Next
    ElseIf IsNumeric(txtLetter.Text) = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a letter.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The text box is empty")
    End If
End Sub

Function listfoods(ByVal letter As String) As String()
    Dim foodarray(foods.Count - 1) As String
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    For Each food As String In foods
        If food.StartsWith(letter) Then
            foodarray(counter) = food
            counter += 1
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve foodarray(counter - 1)
    Return foodarray
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the results of the listfoods function in a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) or similar and associate it with a key if you want to 'Name' it, although its not clear why you need to do this

As for listing the foods starting with the particular letter, you just need to iterate your result of the function listfoods and separate each one by a comma don't you?

What you have now will create many lists of each food as you are getting the list of food beginning with a particular letter for each food..  As I understand the question you only need to do that once.

Example:

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

    Dim Letter As String = txtLetter.Text.ToUpper
    Dim smallerarray() As Array
    Dim userarray As String
    lstOutput.Items.Clear()
    If IsNumeric(txtLetter.Text) = False Then
        'get all items from the file which begin with the letter the user chose
        smallerarray = listfoods(Letter)
        'add that letter to the output listbox
        lstOutput.Items.Add(Letter)
        'join all of the elements which begin with that letter 
        'into a single comma separated string
        userarray = Join(smallerarray, ", ")
        'add that string to the output
        lstOutput.Items.Add(userarray)
    ElseIf IsNumeric(txtLetter.Text) = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a letter.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The text box is empty")
    End If
End Sub
```

it would probably be useful for you to step through the code and see the values of the variable at each place and compare this with what you expect to see if you can see where the actual value differs from what your logically expect so you can start to identify where the issue is

Comment: Thank you for the help Sam. To answer your question, I need to name the new array that is created by the user because in another part of my program I have to write that new array to a text file. I added your response code to my program and I have an underline under:

smallerarry= listfoods(Letter)

and the error message reads: value of type '1-dimensional array of string cannot be converted to '1 dimensional array of System.Array' because 'String' is not derived from 'System.Array'.

I tried stepping through the program but am unsure of where to set the breakpoint because of the error.